# Missing rules XML file for qt's 'uic3 -convert'

Tags: qt, qt4, porting, qt3

I'm trying to run uic3 -convert to convert some QT3 .ui files to QT4.

When I run it, uic3 reports that it's unable to find the rules file (q3porting.xml).

- Where does uic3 look for the q3porting.xml file
- Can I pass the rules file as an argument on the command line (similarly to using qt3to4 -rulesFile)? If not, what else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q3porting.xml` should be in the Qt4 data directory (on my system that's `/usr/share/qt4/`). If it's in the wrong place for some reason you can find it with `locate` (if you have `locate` installed).

There is no option for passing the rules on the command line.